# stringRedisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop("key", 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS) can not close properly

Tags: java, spring-boot, redis

When I run gradle test  project this `String key = stringRedisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop("key", 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);` will be throw error and will not stop

When this jar run on linux shell. It can not be shutdown by press  ctrl + c  and throw error  continually

```java
@PreDestroy
private void destroy(){
  if(!executorService.isShutdown()){
    executorService.shutdown();
   }
}

@PostConstruct
  public void init() {
        RateLimiter errorRate = RateLimiter.create(10);
        executorService
                .submit(() -> {
                    for (; ; ) {
                        try {
                            String key = stringRedisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop("key", 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);
                            if (key != null) {
                                log.warn(key);
                                rateLimiter.acquire();
                            }
                            log.info("nothing.... ");
                        } catch (Exception e) {
                            errorRate.acquire();
                            if (!(e instanceof RedisCommandTimeoutException || e instanceof QueryTimeoutException)) {
                                log.error(e.getMessage(), e);
                            } else {
                                //ignore
                            }
                        }
                    }
                });
    }
```

I want close this process correctly but this line of code 
`stringRedisTemplate.opsForList().leftPop("key", 3, TimeUnit.SECONDS);`
 It throws error continually

error stack trace

```
[2019-04-02 16:47:07] [insert-contact-th] [ERROR] [c.z.f.service.RedisMessageSubscriber] - Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:932)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:785)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations.leftPop(DefaultListOperations.java:80)
    at com.ziggle.fan.service.RedisMessageSubscriber.lambda$init$1(RedisMessageSubscriber.java:72)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:233)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connectStandalone(RedisClient.java:253)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.lambda$null$0(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:74)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$RedisPooledObjectFactory.create(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:225)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$RedisPooledObjectFactory.create(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:215)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:433)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:362)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$1.borrowObject(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:124)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$1.borrowObject(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:80)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task
    at io.netty.resolver.AddressResolverGroup.getResolver(AddressResolverGroup.java:60)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:200)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.access$000(Bootstrap.java:49)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:188)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap$1.operationComplete(Bootstrap.java:174)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListener0(DefaultPromise.java:511)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListenersNow(DefaultPromise.java:485)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.notifyListeners(DefaultPromise.java:424)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.DefaultPromise.trySuccess(DefaultPromise.java:103)
    at io.netty.channel.DefaultChannelPromise.trySuccess(DefaultChannelPromise.java:84)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.safeSetSuccess(AbstractChannel.java:978)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.register0(AbstractChannel.java:512)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe.access$200(AbstractChannel.java:423)
    at io.netty.channel.AbstractChannel$AbstractUnsafe$1.run(AbstractChannel.java:482)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.AbstractEventExecutor.safeExecute(AbstractEventExecutor.java:163)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor.runAllTasks(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:404)
    at io.netty.channel.nio.NioEventLoop.run(NioEventLoop.java:462)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.SingleThreadEventExecutor$5.run(SingleThreadEventExecutor.java:897)
    at io.netty.util.concurrent.FastThreadLocalRunnable.run(FastThreadLocalRunnable.java:30)
    ... 1 common frames omitted
[2019-04-02 16:47:07] [insert-contact-th] [ERROR] [c.z.f.service.RedisMessageSubscriber] - Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
org.springframework.data.redis.connection.PoolException: Could not get a resource from the pool; nested exception is io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:86)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getNativeConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:957)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory$SharedConnection.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:932)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getSharedConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:785)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettuceConnectionFactory.getConnection(LettuceConnectionFactory.java:299)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.doGetConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:132)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisConnectionUtils.getConnection(RedisConnectionUtils.java:82)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:211)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.RedisTemplate.execute(RedisTemplate.java:184)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.AbstractOperations.execute(AbstractOperations.java:95)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.core.DefaultListOperations.leftPop(DefaultListOperations.java:80)
    at com.ziggle.fan.service.RedisMessageSubscriber.lambda$init$1(RedisMessageSubscriber.java:72)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(FutureTask.java:264)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:1128)
    at java.base/java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(ThreadPoolExecutor.java:628)
    at java.base/java.lang.Thread.run(Thread.java:834)
Caused by: io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException: Unable to connect to 127.0.0.1:6379
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisConnectionException.create(RedisConnectionException.java:56)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.getConnection(AbstractRedisClient.java:233)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connectStandalone(RedisClient.java:253)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connect(RedisClient.java:202)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.StandaloneConnectionProvider.getConnection(StandaloneConnectionProvider.java:56)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.lambda$null$0(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:74)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$RedisPooledObjectFactory.create(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:225)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$RedisPooledObjectFactory.create(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:215)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.BasePooledObjectFactory.makeObject(BasePooledObjectFactory.java:58)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.create(GenericObjectPool.java:889)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:433)
    at org.apache.commons.pool2.impl.GenericObjectPool.borrowObject(GenericObjectPool.java:362)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$1.borrowObject(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:124)
    at io.lettuce.core.support.ConnectionPoolSupport$1.borrowObject(ConnectionPoolSupport.java:120)
    at org.springframework.data.redis.connection.lettuce.LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.getConnection(LettucePoolingConnectionProvider.java:80)
    ... 16 common frames omitted
Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: executor not accepting a task
    at io.netty.resolver.AddressResolverGroup.getResolver(AddressResolverGroup.java:60)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect0(Bootstrap.java:200)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.doResolveAndConnect(Bootstrap.java:170)
    at io.netty.bootstrap.Bootstrap.connect(Bootstrap.java:145)
    at io.lettuce.core.AbstractRedisClient.initializeChannelAsync(AbstractRedisClient.java:267)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connectStatefulAsync(RedisClient.java:318)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connectStandaloneAsync(RedisClient.java:276)
    at io.lettuce.core.RedisClient.connectStandalone(RedisClient.java:252)
    ... 28 common frames omitted
```

Comment: Give some parameters to for loop

Comment: It should be   infinite loop I asked this question
`https://jira.spring.io/browse/DATAREDIS-961?focusedCommentId=182689&page=com.atlassian.jira.plugin.system.issuetabpanels%3Acomment-tabpanel#comment-182689`

Comment: With his answer I  am confused with ` no synchronization`  and dont know what to do to solve this problem